# Getting a negative tax in a prestashop order

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, tax

I'm using Prestashop Version 1.6. In my recent order, I got a negative tax value.

Like:

```
TOTAL PRODUCTS  500.00 € 
SHIPPING    0,00 €
TOTAL TAXABLE   500.00 €
VAT     -6,00 €
Total   494,00 €
```

This order should not contain VAT (or atleast not a negative one). I checked the db, where `total_products` field is having `500` and `total_product_wt` field is having `494`. I am not sure what is causing the negative value.

Comment: you sure `total_product_wt`is not `494`? that would make sense with the data you posted before that. Where does the negative value appear? (email, order confirmation, PS backend, DB)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. total_product_wt is 494. Its appearing in order view page

Comment: Updated title to be more easily searchable and cleaned up the grammer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the PDF templates of your invoices?
In doubt try to replace the PDF file at the root by one of a Prestashop downloaded from the same version, and verify that in your chart you do not have a PDF file, otherwise rename it for testing.
Evidently thought to dump your browser cache and site to do the test.